# array pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

How do you access/dereference with arrays in c++??

for example, if I have this code

```
int num[] = {0,1,2,3};
int *p = &num;
```

I thought p was point to the first element in num array?

For some reason, I get a compiler error.

I want to use pointers and increments to access and change the value that is pointing,

for example, p gets the address of the first variable in the int array num and if I increment p, I get the address of the second variable in the int array num.

Any tips would be appreciate it.

Comment: The type of &num is int **.

Comment: @kjpus: actually, the type of `&num` is `int (*) [4]`. The `sizeof` and `&` operators have special meaning for array types.

Comment: @dreamlax actually they have the same meaning for all types; it is the array types which have special meaning in other contexts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I thought p was point to the first element in num array?

No. `int *p = &num;` is wrong, since `&num` is not a pointer to an int, i.e. `int*`, but is actually a pointer to an array of ints, i.e. `int (*) [4]`.

To get a pointer to the first element, you can use `int *p = num;`, or `int *p = &num[0];` instead.